# Flutter - how to use SingleScrollView() to Scroll Entire Screen when Keyboard Appears not just text automatically

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Even After using **`SingleChildScrollView()`** as main Parent, still only the text field is shifted up, but i need to shift up the Login button as well.

The output of my code is Left image but i need the result of right.

I have used Material to custom made a Button.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_catalog/utils/routes.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  String name = "";
  bool changeButton = false;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  moveToHome(BuildContext context) async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      setState(() {
        changeButton = true;
      });

      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      await Navigator.pushNamed(context, MyRoutes.homeRoute);
      setState(() {
        changeButton = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        // color: Colors.white,
        body: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/login.png",
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  height: 100,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 24.0),
                Text("Welcome, $name",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 24,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    )),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20.0,
                ),
                Padding(
                  // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),  //everywhere padding
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Enter Username",
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                height: 2, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            labelText: "Username",
                          ),
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            name = value;
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value!.isEmpty)
                              return "Username cannot be Empty";
                            else
                              return null;
                          }),
                      TextFormField(
                          obscureText: true, //wont show text
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Enter Password",
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                height: 2, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            labelText: "Password",
                          ),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value!.isEmpty)
                              return "Password Cannot be Empty";
                            else if (value.length < 6)
                              return "Password must be Greater than 6 Length";
                          }),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20.0,
                ),

                Material(
                  color: Colors.deepPurple,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(changeButton ? 50 : 8),
                  child: InkWell(
                    // splashColor: Colors.redAccent,
                    onTap: () => moveToHome(context),
                    child: AnimatedContainer(
                      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                      width: (changeButton ? 50 : 150),
                      height: 50,
                      //you can keep color at one place
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: changeButton
                          ? Icon(Icons.done, color: Colors.white)
                          : Text(
                              "Login",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 18),
                            ),
                    ),

                    // ElevatedButton(
                    //   child: Text('Login'),
                    //   style: TextButton.styleFrom(minimumSize: Size(150, 40)),
                    //   onPressed: () {
                    //     Navigator.pushNamed(context, MyRoutes.homeRoute);
                    //     // print('hi');
                    //   },
                  ),
                ) // ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
        ));
  }
}
```

> Ignore This, This is used to allow stackoverflow to show whole code
> Ignore This, This is used to allow stackoverflow to show whole code
> Ignore This, This is used to allow stackoverflow to show whole code
> Ignore This, This is used to allow stackoverflow to show whole code
> Ignore This, This is used to allow stackoverflow to show whole code
> Ignore This, This is used to allow stackoverflow to show whole code
> Ignore This, This is used to allow stackoverflow to show whole code
> Ignore This, This is used to allow stackoverflow to show whole code
> Ignore This, This is used to allow stackoverflow to show whole code
> Ignore This, This is used to allow stackoverflow to show whole code
> Ignore This, This is used to allow stackoverflow to show whole code
> Ignore This, This is used to allow stackoverflow to show whole code
> Ignore This, This is used to allow stackoverflow to show whole code
> Ignore This, This is used to allow stackoverflow to show whole codeIgnore This, This is used to allow stackoverflow to show whole codeIgnore This, This is used to allow stackoverflow to show whole codeIgnore This, This is used to allow stackoverflow to show whole codeIgnore This, This is used to allow stackoverflow to show whole code

Answer (score 3):

SingleChildScrollView(
...

**reverse: false,**

...

)

Answer (score 1):

```
scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 150),
```

to the TextFormField